# How to pull the already deployed cloud function from Firebase Cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed some code on firebase cloud function from another machine. I have changed the machine and I want to pull the existing cloud function here. When I do
`firebase login` and then `firebase init` and select the same project as existing but it still creates **empy index.js** file

Comment: Note, this is now doable it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43916900/2057171

Answer (score 5):

Deployment only works one direction - from a computer to the cloud.  There is currently no way to get your code back from the cloud onto a computer.  Instead, you should be using some sort of source control to manage your code.

Comment: Note, this is now doable it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43916900/2057171