# Is it possible to retrieve Firebase Cloud Function source code?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing some Firebase Cloud Functions but I have need to hide a private key, including from Firebase project admins.

If I embedded this key into my source code and uploaded the code myself, would it be possible for anyone to retrieve the source code and thus the key? Either via Firebase or Google?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get code from firebase console which I deployed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setting an environmental variable:

[Oficial Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?utm_campaign=culture_education_functions_en_06-29-17&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=yt-desc)

Comment: I don't see any mention of it in the documentation, at the bottom there are a couple of extra commands, but none does the getEnviromentals... I have worked with environmental variables in other places like Heroku, and by that experience, I can tell that you can't get them back, that is why is relatively safe, this way different people (using Amazon for example) can use personal keys for local developing and then production get special keys. Please be aware, part of security is to also rotate keys.

Answer (score 10):

The code for your Cloud Functions is never accessible to users of your app.

It is however accessible for the collaborators on your Firebase project. See [Get code from firebase console which I deployed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier)

I don't think there's any way to hide such configuration values from collaborators. Since they can see/deploy code, and the code needs access to this private key, they by definition have access to the key too.

Answer (score 7):

Answering precisely to your question: **Yes, they can**.

The **step by step to achieve** that is relatively simple

1. Go into the [GCP Functions](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) page
2. Select the function you want to inspect
3. Click on source (From there you should be able to see all the files and the code used by that function), or;
4. Click on variables (From there you should see all environment variables used by your function)

If people being able to see env variables is problematic to you, **here's a way to make things more secure**:

You can build on what you already and start encrypting those keys before adding them to the codebase or the environment variables. After that, you can use an encryption service such as [KMS](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/kms) to decrypt those keys at runtime. In KMS itself you can have a stricter policy in there, only allowing yourself and the function to access that service.

Another great service from GCP is [Google's Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)

Comment: How do you reach the GCP Functions from the main console's function dashboard?