# lost my index.js file of firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I accidentally overwritten the index.js file of firebase cloud functions. Can anyone tell me how to get the file. Sorry if this is a stupid question as I am new in javascript (I don't have any knowledge of node.js)

Comment: If you accidentally delete the file you can recover it (depending on operating system as to how). If you replace the contents then you don't have any recourse except through your editor. You may be able to undo your changes, or the editor may keep backup copies of your edits somewhere

Comment: @Mikkel content is replaced and I am using visual studio code for that

Comment: It's already solved here my friend
[Get code from firebase console which I deployed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier)