# GIT branch on Firestore

Tags: firebase, github, google-cloud-firestore

How do we know that what cloud functions are running on Firestore with respect to the GIT branch? Is there versioning we can reference? I mean can we know that what is the branch of the cloud function that is deployed on Fire-store?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions doesn't know anything about your git.  If you want to add some information to your deployment, perhaps added to your source code, or in another file that you deploy, you are free to arrange for that yourself.  None of the provided tooling will do this for you.  Once you've added the information you need to your deployment, you can [view the source code for the current deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier) in the Google Cloud console.