# Download or sync Firebase Functions to local environment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a Firebase project that currently uses several Cloud Functions.
The thing is that I want to download or sync the Cloud Functions to the local environment on my laptop.

I mean some command using `firebase-tools` or another like:

```
git clone [project name]
git fetch [something]
```

Usually, we create some cloud functions using the Firebase Console, and I would like to have these functions locally to edit these when needed and deploy them again.

I know that `firebase-tools` have these two commands, but it is only for configurations:

```
functions:config:clone [options]
functions:config:get [options]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no provided solution for automatically copying or synchronizing functions that have already been deployed.  You can certain [get the source code for deployed functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier), but the Firebase CLI will not automate that process for you.

Ideally, you will want to manage **all** of your functions from the same source control and CLI in order to deal with them all consistent.  Editing functions from the console is primarily a convenience, not a proper deployment mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It is really disappointing. I already knew about the functionality to download the function's files from the Firebase Console, but I think the `firebase-tools` should provide a feature like this to sync the local environment with the cloud.

Comment: You're free to send your feedback to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Shure, I will do it!

Comment: do you know if this is true for cloud functions as well?